# Bootstrap accordion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

At least last two hours I'm trying to get bootstrap accordion to work.

I pick one basic example where accordion works perfectly and here is it on jsfiddle:

[jsFiddle version which work](https://jsfiddle.net/Hajdarevic89/rxkznobt/)

Source code of working version:

```
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion222">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion222" href="#collapse1">
                        Collapsible Group 1</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                    minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                    commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion222" href="#collapse2">
                        Collapsible Group 2</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                    minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                    commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion222" href="#collapse3">
                        Collapsible Group 3</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                    minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                    commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is my example which doesn't work. I can't find out what I missed.

[jsFiddle which doesn't work](https://jsfiddle.net/Hajdarevic89/6Lz4syzp/)

My version which doesn't work:

```
<div class="panel-group uk-row-first" id="accordion222">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading main">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a href="#collapse1" class="panel-toggle collapsed" data-parent="#accordion222" data-body-background="background1.jpg" data-toggle="collapse"> Willkommen </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-body panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-inner main">
                    <p class="uk-article-lead"><span>Test test test</span>               </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading main">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapse6" class="panel-toggle collapsed" data-parent="#accordion222" data-body-background="background6.jpg" data-toggle="collapse"> Kontakt </a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse6" class="panel-body panel-collapse collapse ">
                <div class="panel-inner main">
                    <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-width-medium-1-2">
                        <p> Idem za kanadu! </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in my example accordion doesn't work. I want that opening a new item closes currently open as in first example.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: For me it's working? The only difference is, that opening a new one will close the already opened one. Do you want to get rid of that?

Comment: @Aer0 Yes, that was the point. That is point of accordion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="panel-group uk-row-first" id="accordion222">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion222">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading main">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a href="#collapse1" class="panel-toggle collapsed" data-parent="#accordion222" data-body-background="background1.jpg" data-toggle="collapse"> Willkommen </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-body panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-inner main">
                    <p class="uk-article-lead"><span>Test test test</span>               </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading main">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapse6" class="panel-toggle collapsed" data-parent="#accordion222" data-body-background="background6.jpg" data-toggle="collapse"> Kontakt </a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse6" class="panel-body panel-collapse collapse ">
                <div class="panel-inner main">
                    <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-width-medium-1-2">
                        <p> Idem za kanadu! </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for your accordion
you miss the group id and you also use individual group for each accordion.
merge these accordion in a single group

Comment: Thank you. That was it. 

Is it possible to work in this example with nested accordion ? 

https://jsfiddle.net/Hajdarevic89/x9ea0wkp/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lz4syzp/1/).

The only thing you need to do is to remove the id from your inner `div` and set it up as your parent containers id.

```
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center" id="accordion222">
...
</div>
```